# Strange missing 'dir?' method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber

I've recently started seeing an odd error in my Cucumber tests. Unfortunately I can't trace back to when it was introduced.

There are a number of errors in different places along the lines of

```
undefined method `dir?' for #<Order:0x000000098447f8> (NoMethodError)
```

I don't have (and haven't had) a method anywhere in the code called 'dir?'

Any ideas what might be calling it and how to fix this one?

Update. The code fails with the same message when the page is viewed normally. The code is:

```
def index
  search = {"meta_sort" => "id.desc"}.merge(params[:search] || {})
  @search = @company.orders.search(search)
  @orders = @search.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20).includes(:premise).includes(:address)
end
```

Some almost identical code elsewhere works fine.

```
def index
  @search = @company.users.shoppers.search(params[:search])
  @customers = @search.paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 20
end
```

I tried changing the non-working code to mimic the working code but that didn't make any difference. The search method is provided by the metasearch gem which we've been using happily for a while now.

Update 2:

It would seem that the fault appeared with the introduction of the [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job_active_record) and [workless](https://github.com/lostboy/workless) gems. Workless is dependent on [Rush](https://github.com/adamwiggins/rush), which has a 'dir?' method. I still have no idea why the fault is cropping where it is though.

Comment: A stack trace and/or some code that is causing this to break would be helpful

Comment: Are you using version control? If so, go back until the error goes away. If not, drop what you're doing and start immediately.

Comment: You're passing an order to something that doesn't expect an order. Follow the stacktrace up until you find this place.

Comment: I've created a backtrace as suggested - https://gist.github.com/3397090

Comment: The first non-framework line points here: /home/graeme/Code/lunch/app/controllers/admin/orders_controller.rb:11:in `index'.  What happens when you browse to that action (presumably /admin/orders)?  Could you post the source of the 'index' method in the file mentioned?

Comment: @Beerlington [git bisect](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bisect.html) works wonderfully for that :-)

Comment: Yes, we're using git for version control. I hadn't been able to narrow down the exact point the fault was introduced as it was part of large branch merge. However, with the help of Michael's comment above, I now know how to use git bisect. Awesome tool! Once I've narrowed the problem down further I will update.

Comment: I don't think queries should involve order in this way. Order is for display purposes in search results, not search purposes. The records don't care what order they are in.

Comment: @thekungfuman It's orders plural (i.e. orders belonging to the company) not order singular.

Comment: @Simmo I was referring to `search = {"meta_sort" => "id.desc"}.merge(params[:search] || {})`

Comment: @thekungfuman Apologies. That line is to ensure that there is an order to the records displayed, even if one isn't selected by the user. The default is overridden if the user selects something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a name clash on the *search* method that is defined in Rush and use a *dir?* with the meta_search gem search method

Use ***metasearch*** method instead of *search* for searching with meta_search